# Can I use package.json "resolutions" to substitute in lodash-es for lodash?

Tags: javascript, npm, lodash, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

Pretty straightforward, I'm wondering if resolutions can be used in this fashion (substituting in a *different*) package like you can for dependencies.

```js
  "resolutions": {
    "lodash": "npm:lodash-es@^14.7.x"
  },
```

And if I can do that with NPM or Yarn, are there problems beyond the normal risks if I were to force `lodash` to a certain version.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can work, but I couldn't make it work with Webpack's DLL generation.

```
C:\projects\myProject\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:10
export { default as add } from './add.js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\projects\myProject\node_modules\concurrently\src\flow-control\kill-others.js:1:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```